# ios - How to render CALayer in context with positioning

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cgcontext

I have to put `CALayer` in the `CGContext`

So I found a function `render(in: CGContext)` in class `CALayer` :)

But this is not enough to me :(

Because this function can't position of `CALayer` in `CGContext`

So I tried set value `position` of `CALayer`, but it didn't work as I expected

Is there any way to position it?

This is my code.

```
...

let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let myLayer: CALayer = ...

myLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) // It didn't work as I expected
myLayer.render(in: context)
```

Comment: you try with `CGContextTranslateCTM ` link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455286-cgcontexttranslatectm

Comment: Make sure that your view is configured to use custom layers. Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview especially at "Configuring a View’s Visual Appearance"

Comment: Thanks! I got hints from your comments and found `translateBy` of `CGContext`. And It's working as I wanted when use this.

Comment: @Byoth can you please share your working code?

Answer (score 3):

For people who are still looking for a solution to this problem. You can use [`translateBy(x:y:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455286-translateby) on the context like this:

```
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    context.translateBy(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)
    myLayer.render(in: context)
}
```